# Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/3159): Connections using insecure transport are prohibited while --require_secure_transport=ON

Tags: php, mysql, connection, host

For a project I am trying to make a app wherein users can input their values, however when I am testing this on my localhost I keep receive this error: Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/3159): Connections using insecure transport are prohibited while --require_secure_transport=ON. This is my php code:

```
    $bedrijfsnaam = $_POST['bedrijfsnaam'];
    $dag = $_POST['dag'];
    $caption = $_POST['caption'];

    var_dump($bedrijfsnaam, 
             $dag, 
             $caption);

    $dbh = mysqli_connect(hostname: $host, 
                          username: $username, 
                          password: $password,
                          database: $dbname);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        die("Connection error: " . mysqli_connect_errno());
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO file_upload (bedrijfsnaam, dag, caption)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?)"; 
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
```

Is there a safe way to fix this error as the project will have to be published and from what I understand it would be unsafe to turn off the secure_transport.

[image: Screenshot of the error]

I have tried using another external database which resulted in another error where the connection got actively refuesed. The code does work as I have tried to run it localhost and it did work

Answer (score 0):

You need to be calling [mysqli_real_connect][1] and passing in your $mysqli instance as an argument

```
        $mysqli = mysqli_init();
        if (!$mysqli) {
            die('mysqli_init failed');
        }

        $mysqli->ssl_set(
            '/path/to/client-key.pem',
            '/path/to/client-cert.pem',
            '/path/to/ca-cert.pem',
            NULL,
            NULL
        ); //any paths here will work

        if (!$mysqli->options(MYSQLI_INIT_COMMAND, 'SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0')) {
            die('Setting MYSQLI_INIT_COMMAND failed');
        }

        if (!$mysqli->options(MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 5)) {
            die('Setting MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT failed');
        }
```

then pass to mysqli_real_connect

```
   $dbh = mysqli_real_connect(mysql:$mysqli, hostname: $host, 
                          username: $username, 
                          password: $password,
                          database: $dbname);


  [1]: https://www.w3schools.com/Php/func_mysqli_real_connect.asp
```